# Angular controller: access scope of parent directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I have a directive `myDirective` with a nested controller `myCtrl` (Yes I know that's not a good design practice and I'll be refactoring it later, but I don't have the time to refactor it right now). In the directive I defined a variable `customID`. I need to access `customID` within the scope of `myCtrl`. The catch is, `customID` is unique to each instance of `myDirective`, so (I could be wrong)I don't think a service would work since all instances of `myDirective` would get the same value for `customID`.

Is there an easy way I can pass `customID` from `myDirective` to `myCtrl`?

```
<div myDirective>
    <div id="{{customID}}"></div>
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        {{customID}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you add the source of myDirective and myCtrl to your question. And beware of the CamelCase! myDirective is not a valid name: it should be my-directive if you call the directive itself myDirective.

Comment: `customID` should be available in the scope of `myCtrl`. Controllers do not create isolated scopes.

Comment: Thanks for the advice guys. I ended up going back to the drawing board and refactored my nested controller into a directive, which I could then initialize like so: `<div my-nested-directive custom-id="customID"></div>`

Comment: did you try using scope.$parent, that should work even if your directive has an isolated scope.

Comment: That was one of the first things I tried. When I called `$scope.$parent` from within `MyCtrl` though, I didn't get the scope of `myDirective`. I instead got the scope of the parent controller of `myDirective`. Perhaps `$scope.$parent` doesn't recognize directive scopes because they're isolated?

Comment: true but each isolated scope must have a parent which is usually the scope where it is declared(take this with a pinch of salt) for-eg, ng-repeat has an isolated scope, but it has a parent scope of whichever controller you define it in. Could you may be post a fiddle. That might help us in understanding the doubt.